# How to work with C strings within an Array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

So let's say I have an array of C strings.  I'm trying to create a function that I will tell which two strings (probably by index path) to remove and then add a new string (merge of the other two) to the array.

I don't need the actual merging code, just the code that removes the 2 strings by index path, then adds an additional string to the array.

(I will probably need another function to do the actual merge and that's out of the scope of this question.)

Comment: this additional string is to be added at the end of your array of strings? Does your array have a fixed size? I dont know the rest of the problem, but it seems to be this would be solved better with a linked list of strings. In that case, remove and add operations would be those of a linked list, and I would be happy to help you in that case. For the case of an array of strings, you need to define a bit more your problem, namely, what will happen to the two "holes" left by the two removed strings....

Comment: You may traverse to the element which you want to delete and shift the rest of the array 1 position back...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a string from an array. You would need to mark the index as being deleted and then copy the entire array to another array omitting the marked elements.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I have the array and two index paths, how would this copy work?

Comment: This is a very cumbersome approach. A Linked List would serve this problem tremendously better.

Comment: @ProgramGuy: When you copy the strings in a loop, check if the index being copied is equal to the marked indexes and if so, don't copy it.